# Save OpenLayers 3 map div's innerHTML to restore the map later?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, openlayers-3

I am trying to achieve the following logic that is in the same div as the maps div, when clicking a button the divs content with the map is saved to a variable and the div shows another thing. When clicking another new button on that new view inside the same div the divs content should clear and restore the innerHTML content saved in the variable which is the map view with all divs content.

I tried doing that by saving all innerHTML into a variable and then reasigning it again like so:

```
//When loading the other content
temp_map_html = div_mapa.innerHTML; // Save inner content of the map's div into a variable
div_mapa.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the div.

//When clicking the close button:
div_mapa.innerHTML = "";
div_mapa.innerHTML = temp_map_html; // try to restore html content with the map
temp_map_html = undefined;
```

However, it doesn't work as I expected.
How could I achieve what I want?
I could create another completely different div and place it above the other with the same css placement and size and make the other one not display but I feel the solution I want might be better since I have not to create a brand new div for that, I wanted to reuse the one of the map.
Seems more logically correct to me since both things I want to switch are related one to each other.

I hope you can lend me a hand :-)

Comment: ***but I feel the solution I want might be better*** ....maybe a misleading feeling(copying the innerHTML will not copy attached events and internal references)

Comment: I just found It was easier to just add all html and use display none or whatever needed when needed.